# Angular "Unkown Provider" - how to use a factory within routeProvider configuration?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, ngroute, angularjs-provider

While playing around with Angular I try to understand better how to use factory, services, constants, routing and other core concepts. So I build a simple demo app with node, express, jade and angular.

Now I would like to use a value inside the routeProvider configuration. I created a constant, this works fine. To make it more flexible for future usage I build a factory then, but this fails with "unknown provider". Is this a question of instantiation sequence in Angular? Why I cannot inject the factory into the `.config` section? Before I tried the same with a service instead of a factory, with the same error. Hopefully I didn't make a simple typo or syntax error, so far I didn't find any.

```
angular
  .module('main', [
    'ngRoute'
  ])

  .constant('cApp', {
      'defaultPath': '/home'
  })

  .factory('svcState', function(){
      var appState;

      function getState(){
          return appState;
      }

      function init() {
          appState='/home';
      }

      init();

      return{
          getState: getState
      };
  })

  .config(function($routeProvider, svcState, cApp){

      $routeProvider
          .when('/home', {
              templateUrl: "partials/home"
          })
          .when('/info', {
              templateUrl: "partials/info"
          })
          .otherwise({
              //redirectTo: cApp.defaultPath  // this works fine
              redirectTo: svcState.getState   // this fails with "Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: svcState"
          })

      })

;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`svcState` should be provider rather than service. Because  service/factory won't be accessible inside config phase. You need to change the implementation of `svcState` to provider so that it will be available in config block of angular.

After provider implementation you could inject that provider using `svcStateProvider` in config block.

```
.config(function($routeProvider, svcStateProvider, cApp){

  $routeProvider
      .when('/home', {
          templateUrl: "partials/home"
      })
      .when('/info', {
          templateUrl: "partials/info"
      })
      .otherwise({
          redirectTo: svcStateProvider.getState() //<--change herer
      })

  })
```

Look at [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28262966/2435473) to know more about provider

Comment: fast answer .. thanks a lot! I understand service and factory are derived from provider. But ok, it seems it has to be "real" provider.

Comment: @Rainer yes you need to change your service implementation to provider

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I changed:

```
angular
    .module('main', [
        'ngRoute'
    ])

    .provider('appState', function(){
        var appState;

        this.setState = function(newState) {
            appState = newState;
        };

        this.getState = function() {
            return appState;
        };

        this.$get = function() {
            return appState;
        };

        function init() {appState='/home';}
        init();

    })
    .config(function($routeProvider, appStateProvider){

        $routeProvider
            .when('/home', {
                templateUrl: "partials/home"
            })
            .when('/info', {
                templateUrl: "partials/info"
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: appStateProvider.getState()
            })

    })

;
```

Comment: Hi @pankajparkar, maybe you have another minute? I now try to SET a value this way, but get an error "not a function":
   
`.run(function ($rootScope, appState) {

     $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
    if (next.$$route) {
     appState.setState(next.originalPath); // ERROR: "TypeError: appState.setState is not a function"
    }
   })
  
  })`

Sorry, I still have to learn formatting a bit better here ...