# Using AngularJS Provider with GET and SET

Tags: angularjs

In [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208593/angular-unkown-provider-how-to-use-a-factory-within-routeprovider-configurat/30210053) I did search a solution to use a value in AngularJS during `.config`. I learned I have to use a provider. Now I try to set a value using this provider. It seems there is a limitation with providers, I can set something ONLY during `.config` ? I get the error "TypeError: appState.setState is not a function", but `setState` is a function, at least for my understanding. I'm wrong?

The code:

```
angular
    .module('main', [
        'ngRoute'
    ])

    .provider('appState', function(){
        var appState;

        this.setState = function(newState) {
            appState = newState;
        };

        this.getState = function() {
            return appState;
        };

        this.$get = function() {
            return appState;
        };

        function init() {appState='/home';}
        init();

    })
    .config(function($routeProvider, appStateProvider){

        $routeProvider
            .when('/home', {
                templateUrl: "partials/home"
            })
            .when('/info', {
                templateUrl: "partials/info"
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: appStateProvider.getState()
            })

    })

    .run(function ($rootScope, appState) {

        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
            if (next.$$route) {
                appState.setState(next.originalPath); 
                // -> ERROR: "TypeError: appState.setState is not a function"
            }
        })

    })

;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Provider is like a two-part service, Its minimum form is like a factory:

```
aModule.provider('foo', function() {
  this.$get = function() {
    return 1;
  }
});
```

Then you can inject this in any other service, directive, controller and `run` function:

```
aModule.controller('BarCtrl', function(foo) { ... });
```

Notice how I used `foo` as the name of the provider.

What this does, is inject into the controller what the `$get` **returns**. AKA, if you log `foo` inside the controller you will get **1**.

So what's the point of the provider? Being able to configure the service before the app runs.

```
aModule.provider('foo', function() {
  var appState;

  this.setState = function(newState) {
    appState = newState;
  }  

  this.$get = function() {
    return appState;
  }
});
```

In this case, apart from the `$get` function, we have some other functions. How can we use them? We need to inject the provider itself and **not** the factory within. How can we do that?

```
aModule.config(function(fooProvider) {
  fooProvider.setState('Hello');
}
```

Notice how I used this time `fooProvider` instead of just `foo`. That says that I am injecting the provider itself. That said, the provider can only be injected into `.config` functions and other provider's constructors.

Now if you log `foo` in our controller, we see: **hello**.

I repeat, what you inject in the controller is what the `$get` returns and not the other methods outside it. That is why you can't use `setState` on the `run`, because what you inject there is what `$get` returns.

Comment: Thanks very much! Written very clearly .. I got it. So I think I can work with this in general. For my specific problem in the meantime I realised, that I cannot use a dynamic parameter within .config. So far I understand .config is loaded once and then "static". But this is another question .. context is node, jade, i18next and angular. So again, thanks for your clear answer!